# Prestashop how do i set a module for a single cms page?

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-1.6

I have a module named 'video gallery'. I want it to set for a cms page "video" only . The cms page id is `'12'` . I have tried `{if $cms->id == 12}` in `video_gallery.tpl` doesnt work. Someone please help me thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Go to cms.tpl located in your theme folder and use this there :

```
{if $cms->id == 12}
    {$HOOK_WHERE_YOUR_VIDEO_MODULE_IS_ASSIGNED_TO}
{/if}
```

BR's

Comment: new to prestashop cant find the hook for this module

Comment: can you please provide a module name? If it's a free module then I can check it out for you.

Comment: Its  Video gallery v1.3 by Bl Modules. Thanks for your time buddy

Comment: Well it is assigned by default to big hooks where you probably have some other content positioned as well. But you could ( just for testing ) use this hook displayFooterProduct

Comment: Added this line top of page  {if $cms->id == 12}
    {$displayFooterProduct}
{/if}
  doesnt work

Comment: and i am using  1.4.7.3

Comment: well obviously it doesnt work that way :) Gave you just a hook name. To display it use this ($HOOK_PRODUCT_FOOTER)

Comment: I have tried {$cms->id} to echo the id display nothing .. may be its my version not supporting!

Comment: im not sure but try either this {$cmspages.id_cms eq 12 } or this {$cmspages.id_cms == 12} Should be exact same thing but you never know. And 1.4 presta is fairly new to me :)

Comment: May be i am doing something wrong i tried adding in my theme matrice > cms.tpl still no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

i think the way to access the id is like this:

```
{if $cms.id_cms == 12 } content here {/if}
```

you could use the 'debug popup'/ smarty debug window to see what the 'cms id' variable is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one instead it works perfectly for me :

```
{if $smarty.get.id_cms == 12 }
 {$HOOK_WHERE_YOUR_VIDEO_MODULE_IS_ASSIGNED_TO}
{/if}
```